# Matrix block is unable to use text method

Tags: twig, craftcms

I am brand new to Craft CMS and just learning the basics. I've been following along with the tutorial included in their docs (https://craftcms.com/docs/getting-started-tutorial/) but when I try to enter the template code to display a matrix block I get this error -

Twig Runtime Error – Twig\Error\RuntimeError

Calling unknown method: craft\elements\MatrixBlock::text()

This is the code for the template which is copied straight from the documentation example here https://craftcms.com/docs/getting-started-tutorial/build/templates.html#display-matrix-content

I don't understand how I could be getting an unknown method error on a seemingly basic function that's copied straight from the tutorial?

````
{% extends "_layout.twig" %}

{% set featureImage = {
  mode: 'crop',
  width: 900,
  height: 600,
  quality: 90
} %}

{% block content %}
  <h1 class="text-4xl text-black font-display my-4">{{ entry.title }}</h1>

  <time class="text-sm block pb-4" datetime="{{ entry.postDate | date('Y-m-d') }}">{{ entry.postDate | date('d M Y') }}</time>

  {% if entry.featureImage|length %}
    {% for image in entry.featureImage.all() %}
      <img src="{{ image.getUrl(featureImage) }}" alt="{{ image.title }}" />
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}

  <div class="my-8">
    {% for block in entry.postContent.all() %}
      <div class="my-4">
        {% if block.type == 'text' %}
          {{ block.text }}
        {% elseif block.type == 'image' %}
          {% for image in block.image.all() %}
            <img src="{{ image.url }}" alt="{{ image.title }}" />
          {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endblock %}```


  [1]: https://craftcms.com/docs/getting-started-tutorial/build/templates.html#display-matrix-content
````

Comment: From what I can tell `MatrixBlock` is another collection/group of Elements/Blocks. Did you try to loop the MatrixBlock? `{% for b in block.all() %}{{ b.text }}{% endfor %}`?

Comment: @DarkBee My understanding is that this section is supposed to loop through the matrix field blocks and change the output depending on what the block within the matrix field is
`{% for block in entry.postContent.all() %} {% endfor %}`

Comment: Solved it! My text field within my matrix field had a typo in the handle and name in the field settings in the admin so it wasn't recognising it when I called it.